# Can you please forward me the mail?

Tags: grammaticality

Do I need to add `please` with `Can you` as this is the requesting form?

```
Can you please forward me the mail ?
```

or

```
Can you forward me the mail ?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be grammatically correct is not compulsory, but when we are using such sentences in a professional environment, it is better to use "please" when you are asking for something. So the first one is correct.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to make the request even better for a workplace environment, using the conditional (*could* instead of *can*) would be most appropriate:

`Could you please forward me the mail?`